# How to play music with loop in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to play music with loop when my page init. How can i do this ?
I'm using this code for button click sounds.

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';

class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  AudioCache _audioCache;

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _audioCache = AudioCache(prefix: "assets/audio/", fixedPlayer: AudioPlayer()..setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.STOP));


onPressed: () {_audioCache.play('b1.wav');}
```

Answer (score 0):

AudioPlayers have "onPlayerCompletion", this should help you problem

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer; 

audioPlayer.onPlayerCompletion.listen((event) {
    //Start playing the next music.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `audioplayers` package in flutter. Creating a loop is there in their Documentation [here](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers/example) give it a shot :)